# what is the purpose of Repaint in jsPlumb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, repaint, jsplumb

This maybe a trivial question but I couldn't actually find comprehensive details on this.

Could you please briefly explain the function of repaint? Would be helpful if it could be explained considering the below context within which I'm using it

```
jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
```

Comment: Does the documentation not answer your question? If not, why not? What else do you want to know? https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/utilities.html

Comment: I guess the documentation states the instances where the repaint is applicable. But what I wanted to know is what exactly does repaint do?

Comment: I guess it will recompute the position of all connections and reposition them.

Comment: Oh,okay. Thank you